# Setting up DoorKeeper with multiple Rails/React applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, doorkeeper

I've built multiple Rails/React applications for my company (all in one using Rails 6. Rails renders json to React).

All applications will be on the same domain and eventually, access rights will be done via VPN. For now, I would like to build a Single Sign On app that would give a list of apps to choose from (Accounts, Dashboard, Audits, etc). Based on the users credentials, they may or may not have certain privileges on these applications.

I appears that the Doorkeeper Gem is the way to go and that the SSO app would also be using Devise for User?

I should add but not sure if it makes a difference. Some of the apps are Rails MVC only. Others use Rails api and React frontend.

And do I create a 'portal' app with just User and devise?

Here's a wireframe of the setup:

[image: wireframe outaline]

Comment: have you figured this out?

Comment: I put it all on hold. Went the AWS route.

Comment: What is the AWS route?